# Specify display time of gifs created with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I'm building gifs from a small number of images in a directory with ffmpeg. The images are created individually and not from breaking a video into frames, e.g. I may have 5 images and wish to create a 20 second gif. Is there an option with ffmpeg to specify how long to show each image out of the entire 20 seconds?

Comment: Adapt the method [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/20588/1871).

Comment: `ffmpeg -v warning  -t 20 -frameate 1/5  -i -i img%03d.png  -vf scale=300:-1 -gifflags -transdiff -y bbb-notrans.gif`

Comment: duration of 5 seconds (the inverse of 1/5 frames per second)

Comment: Try I think will help